# Decorate tikz path with cyrillic text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to decorate tikz path with cyrillic symbols without any success. I can use ASCII symbols but not cyrillic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\path[
   postaction={
     decorate,
     decoration={
       text along path,
       reverse path=false,
       text={very long long text}
     }
  }
] (0,0) circle (1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I put cyrillic symbols in `text={}` this cause many errors.

**UPDATE:** I have processed my tex file with XeLaTex and it works partially. It shows only first symbol.

Also I need to pass the text as parameter as follow:

```
\newcommand\PathWithText[1]{
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\path[
  postaction={
    decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        reverse path=false,
        text={#1}
      }
    }
] (0,0) circle (1cm);
}
\PathWithText{очень длинный текст}
```

Comment: also breaks for other symbols like `äöü` (just in case someone doesn't have cyrillic symbols). Also very funny result with `$a$` as text ;)

Comment: You need to enclose them in braces, e.g.: `text={{ä}{ö}{ü}}`.

Comment: This has to do with the way the text is parsed, one token at a time; but cyrillic letters are multibyte, so the parser gets confused. The same if `ä` is used in Latin script. The trick by @Qrrbrbirlbel works.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Unfortunattely, your solution doesn't work

Comment: Braces as suggested by @Qrrbrbirlbel works but it looks as if for cyrillic you sometimes need more layers of braces. E.g. `text={{{о}}{{ч}}{{е}}{{н}}{{ь}}}` works, but I also had cases where I needed one additional layer around some chars.

Comment: May I suggest Ulrike Fischer's as a more appropriate answer to the question than the one that has been checked? Having to switch to another engine; e.g., from pdflatex to xelatex, seems to me more like a way out avoiding the problem, as opposed to solving it. I was having the same kind of trouble with diacritic marks, had the idea to brace the problematic characters, but the problem remained until I followed Ulrike's advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `LuaLaTex` or `XeLaTex` like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\setmainfont{Liberation Sans} %use some font with cyrillic symbols


\newcommand\PathWithText[1]{
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\path[
  postaction={
    decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        reverse path=false,
        text={#1}
      }
    }
] (0,0) circle (1cm);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\PathWithText{очень длинный текст}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am going to see if it feets my needs. Also, please see my updated question.

Comment: @bronislav I think, your example works for me. I updated the answer to show that I can see all symbols.

Comment: thx, you suggestion works perfect. I am going to ask a new question as a continue of this one.