# center text along tikz path after a shift

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-path

I elaborated upon [Decorate tikz path with cyrillic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150818/decorate-tikz-path-with-cyrillic-text)

to develop an example:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1 cm);
\path[
   postaction={
     decorate,
     decoration={
       text along path,
       reverse path=true,
       raise=-0.3cm,
       %text align={left indent = {0.75\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}},
       text={very long text}
     }
  }
] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I would like to place the text on top of the ellipse. For this I uncomment this line:

```
text align={left indent = {0.75\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}},
```

The output is

[image]

What is left is to replace `left` with `center`. Unfortunately then the document does not compile. How to solve?